# Load jQuery content inline in Lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I have next requirement : 
Need to add light-box with custom inline content : when click on link(anchor) to open jQuery before/after slider .
So i installed fancybox and added all needed parameters and problem is next : when click on link, Fancy lightbox is opened , but no desired content . 
Right click-> Inspect element and voila - before/ after slider is appearing.
So point is that i need to do right click/inspect element to slider be appeared in fancy box .
I suppose problem is in synchro of two jQuery, or initialization.
 [Here is the link](http://vertustech.pejinsystems.com/gallery/) .
Also here is javaScript code i use :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#firpi1").twentytwenty();
});
</script>

<a class="fancybox" id="inline" href="#data">This shows content of element who has id="data"</a>
<div style="display:none">
<div id="data">

<div id="firpi1">
  <img src="http://media5.pejinsystems.com/2015/09/places-before.png">
  <img src="http://media5.pejinsystems.com/2015/09/places-after.png">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

First code to initialize fancybox second one for starting before-after slider.

Comment: The link you provided is showing nothing, and there are no source code.

Comment: Link IS showing  text "This shows content of element who has id=”data”" 
When clicked on that, fancybox is loaded .

Comment: A separate issue is you are loading 2 different versions of jQuery. You need to load only one.

Comment: @Macsupport can you tell me how do you mean ?

Comment: If you look at the scripts you are loading, you have jQuery 2.1.0 loaded first and later in the page you load jQuery  1.11.3. You need to load only one version of jQuery and have it load before all your other jQuery plugins.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but do you have any idea about my problem above?